# Custom week labels with unordered result

Tags: core-plot

I am using Core Plot to draw a graph with custom labels.

It has 7 labels with week such as "Sun", "Mon" and "Tue". And the label may start with each day.

I have ordered the sequence in a `NSMutableSet` or `NSMutableOrderedSet` and then assign to `x.axisLabels`.

However, the `axisLables` is an unordered `NSSet` so my labels get unordered, too.

For example, I set the sequence with string:

```
"Mon", "Thu", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun".
```

But the graph shows the sequence:

```
"Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Thu", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri".
```

Definition of `axisLabels` in core plot.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSSet *axisLabels;
```

Any suggestions for me? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure where you've found that definiton of `axisLabels`, it's `@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong, nullable) CPTAxisLabelSet *axisLabels;` in my copy of CorePlot (v2.2) - each CPTAxisLabel has `offset` and `tickLocation` properties that tell CorePlot where to place it.

Comment: Ok, let me try the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets have no defined order. Core Plot uses the `tickLocation` of each label to position them along the axis.